# Changing height of all elements with same type of ids at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; top: 90px; left: 90px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% black; width: 800px;"
    id="mainDiv">
<div style="width: 405px;" class="floatLeft" id="mainDiv3">
<div style="width: 100%;" id="mainDiv31">
<div style="width: 107px; height: 100%;" class="floatLeft"
    id="mainDiv313"></div>

<div
    style="width: 2px; height: inherit; background-color: white; cursor: default;"
    class="floatLeft" id="mainDiv31_vertical"></div>

<div style="width: 296px; height: 100%;" class="floatLeft"
    id="mainDiv314"></div>
</div>

<div
    style="height: 2px; width: 100%; background-color: white; cursor: default;"
    id="mainDiv3_hotizontal"></div>

<div style="height: 311px; width: 100%;" id="mainDiv32"></div>
</div>

<div
    style="width: 2px; height: inherit; background-color: white; cursor: default;"
    class="floatLeft" id="mainDiv_vertical"></div>

<div style="width: 393px;" class="floatLeft" id="mainDiv4">
<div style="height: 456px; width: 100%;" id="mainDiv41"></div>

<div
    style="height: 2px; width: 100%; background-color: white; cursor: default;"
    id="mainDiv4_hotizontal"></div>

<div style="height: 142px; width: 100%;" id="mainDiv42"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Now I want to change the height of all elements with id's ending with `_vertical` to be automatically set to its parent height, I mean it should get resized automatically in case its parent's div's height increses that increase will be due to addition on some more elements to its botherly div.

For example:

On adding some stuff to `mainDiv313` will increase its parent height i.e. `mainDiv31` height which in turn should increase `mainDiv31_vertical`

What should be assigned to height of `mainDiv31_vertical` so that it exhibits this behavior. i would prefer not changing it by JS or Jquery as it increases processing...

Already set it to `inherit` as it will make it inherit the height from parent.

Please suggest something.

EDIT

i want something like

```
div1 -->div11
       >div1_vertical
       >div12
```

this means `div1` has these 3 other div in it on change `div11` height `div1_vertical`height should change automatically without some js or jquery i want some css property 
i haven' mentioned any height on div1 so it automatically adjusts it children

Comment: I'd simplify that layout and use classes. For some CSS3 selectors, look here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* do this with jQuery:

```
$("div[id$='_vertical']").height(function(){
  return $(this).parent().height();
});
```

But dear lord, you shouldn't. IDs should be unique and semantic, not descriptive of a property. That's what classes are for. Use a class="vertical" instead

Comment: In his exemple ids are uniques but i agree a class is more accurate.

Comment: i know we should use unique ids and i am using them uniquely. but i was not using power of jQuery before and was using plane javascript thats why needed identifier for those special divs hence created like it

Answer (score 3):

To set all `div` elements with an id that ends with `_vertical`, this should do the trick:

```
$("div[id$='_vertical']").height(function(){
    return $(this).parent().height();
});
```

However, it is not possible to do this automatically when the parent height is changed because there are no events to bind to when it comes to DOM manipulation and mutation.

I also agree with Roland that you shouldn't have `_vertical` in your id, but rather as a separate class.

Here's an example using CSS with relative/absolute positioning that might work for you.

**CSS**

```
div.vertical {
    position: relative;
}

div.vertical div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="mainDiv31" class="vertical">
    <div id="mainDiv313"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to wrap my parent height in a function, oops. But you missed an ending bracket, ha! Denmark-Sweden 1-1

Comment: @Jens, Haha! Actually, the bracket is in there but it's not showing?! [See proof](http://gyazo.com/784bacbfaf2330b6ff8c7b9bcc03f5a1.png) Edit: Ah, must be a cache issue. I see that you edited my answer. Thanks!

Comment: this wont change the height of element with vertical at the end of id when a divs height is increased that is child of parent of vertical

Comment: @Valun, I'm not sure I'm following. Do you want to change the height of the parent or the child? You are stating in your question that you want to set the height of the newly appended child to the same of its parent, or did I misunderstand that?